# Etymology of 赤字/黒字

Tags: etymology

赤字 and 黒字 seem to correspond directly to the English expressions 'red ink' and 'black ink', meaning a (financial) deficit/loss and surplus, respectively. If Wiktionary is to be trusted, Mandarin, Cantonese and Korean [use 赤字 in the same way](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B5%A4%E5%AD%97). Furthermore, French has the expression *être dans le rouge* ('to be in the red').

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=red+ink) lists the first recorded instance of 'red ink' in English as being from 1929, and [語源由来辞典](http://gogen-allguide.com/a/akaji.html) asserts that 赤字 and 黒字 spread in Japanese during the 大正時代 (1912-1926) to the start of 昭和時代 (1926-1989).

How did 赤字 and 黒字 come to be used in Japanese? Are the terms borrowed from a European language (or vice versa), or did the practice of using red ink for losses and black ink for profits arise independently?

Comment: Maybe due to the massive losses from the US 1929 stock market crash, and the storied "stockbrokers jumping out of windows"?

Comment: Maybe :) I don't have access to the Oxford English Dictionary at present, but there might be more information to be found there. Etymonline tends to match with what's in the OED.

Comment: Here's [another link](http://www.uraken.net/language/gogen08.html) that possibly points to the 1929 stock market crash as being somewhat related to this sort of usage. *(Linked page is in Shift_JIS encoding.)*

Comment: *In the red* appeared in English in print in [1926](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/202000.html) and is probably older, so user3169's speculation is not correct.  (The OED gives the same cite, and 1928 for *in the black*.)

Comment: @snailplane Nice link... but isn't the OP partly wondering about the Japanese side of when those words came about (or at least came to be used in Japanese?)

Comment: @snailplane Oh well, it sounded good. Good thing I phrased it as a question. Anyway, check (http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/in_the_red_loss_in_the_black_profit_red_ink_black_ink) under "Google Books - Campbell’s Actual Accounting" which is a reference from 1911. My idea is that Japanese usage was borrowed/transferred from English due to western influence in the early 20th century.

Comment: This came up before, and although the question here is not a duplicate, you might want to see the comments on [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11218/119).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the years, I've found Shogakukan's 国語大辞典【こくごだいじてん】 (KDJ) to be a good resource for etymologies and term dating.  Their entry [here at Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%B5%A4%E5%AD%97-186590#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8) lists a first citation in Japanese to 1929, roughly in line with the appearance of the term *"in the red"* in English, dated to 1926 [in this Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_red).

The Japanese Wikipedia article on [黒字【くろじ】と赤字【あかじ】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BB%92%E5%AD%97%E3%81%A8%E8%B5%A4%E5%AD%97) lists a slightly later appearance in 1931, close enough to the KDJ for rough purposes.  This article notes that the Japanese term may have arisen as follows (my explanatory addition [in square brackets]):

> 日本語【にほんご】の「赤字【あかじ】」「黒字【くろじ】」は、この西洋【せいよう】式【しき】簿記【ぼき】に直接【ちょくせつ】由来【ゆらい】するか、あるいは上記【じょうき】の西洋語【せいようご】からの借用【しゃくよう】と見【み】られる。
>     The Japanese terms "red figures" and "black figures" may be derived directly from this Western bookkeeping [writing income and gains in black, and expenditures and losses in red], or they may be borrowings from the aforementioned Western languages.

Answer (score 2):

In bookkeeping, [losses were written in red](http://gogen-allguide.com/a/akaji.html). [Gains were written in black](http://gogen-allguide.com/ku/kuroji.html).

This starts from this.